# Viro Media Cannot Connect to Server

Tags: android, react-native, viro-media

I am working on a Viro Media project with three other people.  Two of us have Android, and two of us have iPhones.  When one of the iPhone people ran the testbed server with an ngrok link, it seems that both of the iPhone users were able to connect to the testbed.  However, when I (android user) and the other android user try connecting to the same link, we get "Error connecting to package server" and "Could not connect to development server" after reloading it.  The two of us (android users) decided to run it locally on our own machines to test it while both our server and our phone is connected to the same wifi, and we are both still receiving this error.  I can confirm that we all have ViroReact 2.17.0.  Is there some extra setup necessary in Android to get this working?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of troubleshooting, we figured out the problem.  For anyone in the future running into this error, when you put the ngrok link into the app, you must delete out http:// out of the link for it to work.